# we did not know how many

Tags: meaning, postmodification

> a. The professor who had published we knew not how many articles started speaking.
>
> b. The professor who had published we did not know how many articles started speaking.

We didn't know how many articles a specific professor had published. That professor started speaking.

Would you say that (a) and (b) imply that that professor had published a great number of articles?

Answer (score 2):

From googling 'knew not how many', I see you have already asked this question on another forum.

Yes, the idiom implies 'a lot' - too many to count easily. My impression is that the inverted form with 'knew not', although archaic in style, sounds more natural than the modernised version (if you're the kind of person who uses expressions like that). If you prefer to stick to modern language, it would be better to say simply *...who had published many articles*.

Answer (score 1):

> Would you say that (a) and (b) imply that that professor had published a great number of articles?

- *we didn't know how many*
- *we knew not how many*

It's implied the number of published articles must be greater than three, but  it could be as few as ten or as many as a hundred. If the OP wishes to convey the professor's productivity, the word "many" or any one of its synonyms should be used.

> The professor who had published **innumerable articles**—exactly how many we didn't know /knew not, started speaking.